# re.sub replace underline inside second group

Tags: python, regex

I am trying re.sub in python, where I want to capture two groups and replace with a new sentence. The first group is "cat" and the second group is "amazing hat". "cat" is the first words/number before (dot) , and "amazing_hat" is anything before ".today"

The closest thing I manage to do is with the following

```
example_sentence = "cat.is.in.the.amazing_hat.today"
regex_command = r'^(.*)\.is\.in\.the\.(.*)\.today'
search_test = re.sub(regex_command, r"\1 bought \2", example_sentence)
print search_test
```

and the result that I get is "cat bought amazing_hat", while I want "cat bought amazing hat" (the amazing_hat should be replaced with amazing(space)hat).

There are of course possibility that I can do for the example above like replacing the string of "_" with " " , but I want to know if I can get "cat bought amazing hat" with re.sub in one go.

Comment: Are you looking for the specific words "cat" and "amazing_hat"? Or are you looking for the first word and "amazing_hat"? Either way, you can put amazing_hat in your regex and replace it with the literal text "amazing hat".

Comment: Unless you want to be very specific (i.e. how many underscores can there be in the second match) you cannot do this in one go. For regular expressions to work your patterns have also to be regular.

Comment: @AndyG : "cat" can be any word/number before the first dot, and "amazing_hat" can be any word/number before (dot)today. today is a static word. so the \2 can be anything e.g. "wonderful_red_car" that will be "wonderful red car"

Comment: .. your regex also shows that you are looking for the very specific phrase `.is.in.the.`. This is so specific that it is overkill to use regex.

Comment: Anyway, now that it's clarified, I would just replace the underscores, or write it across several statements. I'll leave it for someone else who might want to attempt to do it in one statement. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a replacement function that applies a simple string replace on the second group:

```
search_test = re.sub(regex_command, lambda m : "{} bought {}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2).replace("_"," ")), example_sentence)
```

I don't know if it qualifies as "in one go", but that works, and only 1 regex substitution is performed.

Comment: That's good. I did play around with this and tried to exclude the underscores while capturing words `^\b(\w+)\b\.is\.in\.the\.((([a-zA-Z]+(?:_))+)\w+(?:_)?)\.today` [not working, in that it still collects the underscores], or by using positive lookahead. But we wouldn't know how many words/groups there were, so wouldn't be able to do this in one fell swoop.

Comment: @AndyG exactly. That doesn't sound realistic if you don't know what to expect. That's why I decided to post a slightly deviant answer :)